# Sumar valores diferentes MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla con tres columnas el la cual una de las columnas tiene el id_cliente(columnaA), en la segunda los pedidos realizados(columnaB) y en la ultima la fecha del pedido(columnaC)

```
columnaA    columnaB    columnaC

   1           26      2018-02-09
   1           15      2018-02-10
   2           4       2018-02-09
   3           32      2018-02-09
   3           18      2018-02-10
```

Necesitaria sacar el total de pedidos de cada cliente en un rango de fechas
 (2018-02-01/2018-02-28)

```
columnaA    columnaB(sum_total)

   1           41
   2           4
   3           50
```

He probado con esta consulta pero solo me saca un registro:

```
SELECT distinct columnaA, sum(columnaB) as total FROM tabla.pedidos
where columnaC BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28';

columnaA    columnaB(total)

    1           95
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utiliza esta sentencia haber si te sirve

```
SELECT SUM(columnaB) AS total FROM tu_nombre_bd 
WHERE columnaC BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28'
GROUP BY columnaA;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he tenido que modificar un poco tu sentencia pero me ha servido perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Debería ser algo como esto ya que muestra el total de la **columnaB**:

```
SELECT columnaA, sum(columnaB) as total FROM tabla.pedidos
where columnaC BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28'
Group by columnaA
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT columnaA as NIT_CLIENTE
,SUM(columnaB) AS TOTAL_PEDIDOS 
FROM tabla.pedidos
WHERE columnaC BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28'
GROUP BY columnaA`

ten presente lo siguiente:
la columnaC te va a buscar correctamente porque esta en año mes día y es de tipo string, si lo tienes en otro formato de fecha ese string vas a tener problemas.